# What are alternate ways of passing blocks only when block was given?

Tags: ruby

Or simply, how could this code be written in a less repeating version? Or maybe more efficiently?

```
if block_given?
  render(*options, &block)
else
  render(*options)
end
```

Comment: btw, you should be accepting helpful answers :)

Comment: sorry, just accepted. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use block parameter. It handles both situations.

```
def foo(*options, &block)
  bar(*options, &block)
end
```

Example:

```
def bar(*options)
  p options
  p yield if block_given?
end

foo(1)
# >> [1]

foo(2) { 'hello' }
# >> [2]
# >> "hello"
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland: yeah, I should have attached a runnable snippet. :)

Comment: For disbelievers: `def bar(options, &block); puts block_given? ? block.call(3) : "no block"; end; end`. Then `foo(1) { |n| puts "#{n} blind mice" } #=> "3 blind mice"` and `foo(1) #=> "no block"`. Alternatively, `block.call(3)` can be replaced by `yield 3` if there's no need for bar to pass the proc block on to another method. (This is a revision of an earlier comment.)